# How to compare between two different data?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm making a new application, one of the feature of this application is that a user can interact only with his phone contacts ( Same concept as WhatsApp).

I'm using Parse.com as a backend of my app, Users signed up first with their phone numbers, then I should compare all the user's contacts and contacts in backend, to retrieve only the commun contacts ( and store then in SQL)

So do you have any Idea how to make this function better, or any better idea to compare ? it consumes a lot of Bandwidth this function

```
 public void sync_contacts(){

        String phoneNo;
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

                        phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        phoneNo =  phoneNo.replace(" ", "");
                        phoneNo = phoneNo.replace("+33","0");
                        Log.d(name, phoneNo);
                        ParseQuery query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                        query.whereEqualTo("username",phoneNo);
                        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null ){
                                    contacts c = new contacts();
                                    if (!(parseObject.get("Name").toString()==null))    c.setName(parseObject.get("Name").toString());
                                    if (!(parseObject.get("username").toString()==null)) c.setNumero(parseObject.get("username").toString());
                                    ParseFile image = (ParseFile)parseObject.get("Profilepic");
                                    if(!(image==null))
                                    {
                                        c.setProfil(image.getUrl());
                                    }
                                    c.setShow("true");
                                    s.addcontact(c);
                                 Log.d("Found","IO");
                                }
                                else {
                                    Log.d("NotFound","IO");
                                }
                            }
                        });


                    }

                    pCur.close();
                }
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand question.  I'm sure there are limitless things you could do to make any software better.  I don't know what "it consumes a lot of brand with this function" means.

Comment: @CharlesSpencer Sorry I ment bandwidth

Comment: The word "bandwidth" is still unclear.  Does this function take too long to execute or lock up your application?  Does it consume too much memory or cause any errors?

Comment: Yeah it does consume much memory, it takes so much time too

Comment: It's hard to tell what might cause it, but is it possible that the URI is bad?  Have you tried stepping through it in the debugger to see where exactly it is taking a long time?